# FramworkElement Arrange not placing child FramworkElement

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, measureoverride, arrangeoverride

I have two classes [applicable to this question]. The first, `XYAxes2`, extends `FrameworkElement`. It overrides `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` in an attempt to place it's sole child, `XAxis` (also extends `FrameworkElement`), in the desired position.

`XYAxes2` (Parent):

```
Scale XAxis =//...
protected override Size MeasureOverride( Size availableSize ) {
    XAxis.Measure( availableSize );
    return (Size)availableSize;
}
protected override Size ArrangeOverride( Size finalSize ) {
    XAxis.Arrange( new Rect( 50, 50, 100, 200 ) );
    return finalSize;
}
```

`Scale` is a custom drawn component.
`Scale` (Child):

```
protected override void OnRender( DrawingContext cx ) {
    ValidateTicks();
    if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal) {
        cx.DrawLine( Pen, new Point( -.5, .5 ), new Point( ActualWidth - .5, .5 ) );
        foreach (double tick in _ticks.Keys) {
            double val = ScaleTransformCallback( tick );
            double x = -0.5 + (int)((val - MinValue) * ActualWidth / (MaxValue - MinValue));
            cx.DrawLine( Pen, new Point( x, .5 ), new Point( x, TickLength - .5 ) );
            FormattedText txt = _ticks[tick];
            cx.DrawText( txt, new Point( x - txt.Width / 2, TickLength + TextMargin ) );
        }
    } else {
        double Left = maxTextWidth + 2 * TextMargin;
        double Right = this.TickLength + Left;
        cx.DrawLine( Pen, new Point( Right - .5, +.5 ), new Point( Right - .5, ActualHeight + .5 ) );
        foreach (double tick in _ticks.Keys) {
            double val = ScaleTransformCallback( tick );
            double y = -0.5 + ActualHeight - (int)((val - MinValue) * ActualHeight / (MaxValue - MinValue));
            cx.DrawLine( Pen, new Point( Right - .5, y ), new Point( Left - .5, y ) );
            FormattedText txt = _ticks[tick];
            cx.DrawText( txt, new Point( Left - txt.Width - TextMargin, y - txt.Height / 2 ) );
        }
    }
}
```

When debugging, `ActualWidth` in this function is always the width of the parent rather than the width set by `ArrangeOverride`, 100. The child is, however, clipped to the region specified by `ArrangeOverride`.

Am I do something wrong in one of these functions?

**Edit:** By inserting `XAxis.Measure(100,200)` into `ArrangeOverride`, the problem is apparently fixed. Surely, it shouldn't be necessary to call `Measure` everytime the arrangement is invalidated (this would mean `InvalidateArrange` would need to implicitly call `InvalidateMeasure`). Can anyone shed any light on the causes behind this?

Does anyone know where `DesiredSize` and `ActualWidth/Height` are actually set (obviously they are not set by my code)?

Comment: DesiredSize normally gets set after Mesasure pass, ActualWidth/Height set after the controls gets Arranged/Rendered(?). By the sound of it you'll need to call Measure(double.PositiveInfinity, doublePositiveInfinity); After all I don't think Draw* will fit into Measure/Arrange layout paradigm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I have used for this is to use multiple passes in the `MeasureOverride` function. I keep measuring with different sizes until a suitable overall size is determined.

By reading through the .Net 4.0 source code, it appears that :-

- `DesiredSize` is set by the `UIElement.Measure` function to be the
  return value of `MeasureOverride`.
- `ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight` (`RenderSize`) are set by
  `FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore` to be whatever value is returned from
  `ArrangeOverride` There doesn't appear to be any error checking or
  rounding applied.

I hope this can help other people.